# void funct(int (*compare)(a,b))

Tags: c, struct, compare, declaration

I'm trying to do a exercise that my teacher gave me in C but I'm stuck here

this is my code:

```
typedef struct First_s
{
    double a;
    double b, c;
    double d;
} First_t;

typedef struct Second_s
{
    char e[10];
    long f;        
    First_t g; 
} Second_t;

int compare(Second_t *x, Second_t *y)
{
    if(x.g.b >y.g.b){
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
void sortList(Second_t list[], long len, int (*compare) (Second_t *a, Second_t *b)){
}
```

Can anybody tell me how can I use this *compare function.
I looket for it on internet but I really don't know how to find it, because I don't know how this kind of function is called.

Thank You :)

Comment: You post a compiler error message as your title, but then never refer to compilation problems in your question. What are you asking?

Comment: sorry, I changed it imediately. That wasn't thought :(

Comment: *compare is a pointer to a function. Pass a function for that argument, . . . . like your "int compare" function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I'm asking how can I use this (*compare) (Second_t *a, Second_t *b) that is inside the void sortlist() argument

Comment: @user3344003 but how do I use it inside the void sortList() function,
when i try to do it as:
if(compare(a,b) == 0)
it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to switch to the answers for this because of length.

If appears from what you have above that you want to get to something like

```
Second_t    somelist [5000000000] ;
. . . .

sortList (somelist, 5000000000, compare) ;
```

You do not state this but the context suggests the goal is to have a generic sort function that can handle different methods of comparison. The comparison method is specified as a function parameter to  sortList().

```
 Second_t a, b ;

 if (compare (&a, &b))
```

Should work.

Comment: thank you :D that was very helpful. I can't give you a +1 because my reputation is below 15 :(. 
And something else, is it bat that is giving me an warning at the line where sortList() function stands and in the line where sortlist is defined

Comment: That depends, what's the warning? "Is it bad that I get a warning?" is like "Is it bad that a yellow light is on?"

Answer (score 1):

You can call the compare function in sortList like this:

```
int a, b;
(*compare)(&a,&b)
```

Comment: thank you. sorry for not giving a +1 but I can't because my reputation is below 15 :(

Comment: You can omit the `(*` and first `)` altogether for better readability.